# How to replace rows in Hive database using HQL

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I'm trying to filter out a hive database df

```
project  schedule  timestamp
p1       1         t1
p1       2         t1
p1       3         t1
p2       1         t2
p2       2         t2
```

I want to replace rows in this data in such a way that the resultant dataset is something like :

```
project schedule timestamp
p1      2        t1
p1      3        t1
p2      1        t2
p2      2        t2
```

The query i was trying to use was :

```
Insert overwrite table df Select * from df where project != p1 and schedule != 1.
```

This is not working as i filter out the all rows of project p1. I kinda think I'm missing something very trivial here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the logic you want is:

```
where project <> 'p1' or schedule <> 1
```

Or equivalently:

```
where not (project = 'p1' and schedule = 1)
```

Comment: Trivial to say the least. I think I need a break.